# Does Keras OCR support other languages?

Tags: python, keras, ocr

I am trying to extract text from image using [keras-ocr](https://pypi.org/project/keras-ocr/). Does it support other written languages?

I am not getting proper documentation for supporting other languages.

Comment: It's not clear to me if the question is about programming language or language like english or korean.